# Как можно открыть диалоговое окно (alert или window или modal, с надписью), только после второго клика на кнопку?

Tags: jquery, modal, alert

Всем привет!  Т.е. получается, что после первого события клика, выполняется некий код, а если второй раз нажмёт кнопку пользователь, вот тогда и нужно, чтобы открылось окно с надписью, мол, "Вы уже сделали выбор!"
Как это можно реализовать? Подскажите пожалуйста .... Где и какой код разместить? Спасибо за внимание!
Пример Jquery:

```
$("#btnLike").on('click', function() {
    //........код
    //........код

    var ajax = $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: "https://site.com/like.php",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
          'like': 1
        }
    });
      ajax.done(function() {
        //......результат;
    });
    $("#btnLike").on('click', function() {
        alert('Вы уже проголосовали!'); //  где разместить??  Тут не работает!
        window['alert']('Вы уже проголосовали!'); // или здесь?  И тут не работает!
    });
});
```

Comment: добавьте переменную, условно, `let clickCounter = 0;` перед добавлением события, и уже внутри функции события проверяете "кол-во нажатий" `if ( clickCounter > 1 ) { alert("Вы уже сделали выбор!" ); return false; }`, и после проверки уже увеличиваете счетчик `clickCounter++;`

Comment: Отличная идея! Мне понравилась ...., но почему-то у меня не получается достичь нужного эффекта.

Comment: Добавьте Ваш вариант, как пробовали - поправим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
let counter = 0;

$("#btnLike").on('click', function() {
    if (counter == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: "https://site.com/like.php",
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                'like': 1
            }
        }).done(function() {
            counter++
            //......результат;
        });
    } else {
        alert ('Вы уже голосовали.')
    }
});
```

Comment: Супер! Благодарю.